# nodes with rel axis cs are not shown in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

With pgfplots, I'm trying to add text to a relative position according to the axis.

If the position is inside the figure, this works well, but when I want to add the text outside the figure, the text is hidden.

On the ECM below, we see that the first text appears well in the figure, but the second one is cut by the top part of the figure.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [y expr=\thisrowno{1}] {
1 3
2 5
3 4
};
\node [anchor=south west] at (rel axis cs: 0., .5)  {Additional text inside the plot};
\node [anchor=south west] at (rel axis cs: 0., .95) {Additional text outside the plot};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to see this second text ?

Comment: Adding the option `clip=false` to the `axis` environment will prevent the clipping.

Comment: To continue @Jasper Habicht 's comment, note that the relative position given by `(rel axis cs: 0, 0)` for example is slightly different inside and outside the `axis`.

Comment: Note that you can specify `[name=foo]` to get the axis box defined as a node (more or less).  For example you can use `\node[above right] (foo.north west) {Additional text outside the plot};` **outside** the axis environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just need to add the option `clip=false` to the axis environment :

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[clip=false]
\addplot table [y expr=\thisrowno{1}] {
1 3
2 5
3 4
};
\node [anchor=south west] at (rel axis cs: 0., .5)  {Additional text inside the plot};
\node [anchor=south west] at (rel axis cs: 0., .95) {Additional text outside the plot};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the text is not clipped at compilation !

[image: result]

another way to do it is to name the axis and refer to it outside the axis environment.

This answer is a gathering the information from the comments of the initial post. Thanks !